# R Encoding Holiday Vectors optionally using timeDate package

Tags: r, date, time-series, forecasting, arima

the `timeDate` package in R provides a list of holidays that I would like to include in a timeseries dataset. If I call `timeDate::listHolidays("US")` i get a vector of US holiday names that correspond to function names in the timeDate package. I would like to programmatically loop through these lists of holidays and get the date value for a given year (or years).

Something like

```
hdates <- list()
i <- 1
for (h in timeDate::listHolidays('US')) {
    hdates[[i]] <- h(2018)
    i <- i + 1
}
```

This of course doesn't work because `h` is a string/character not a function. Is there any way to programmatically grab a named function from a Namespace? I'm also open to other methods for extracting dates for MULTIPLE holidays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `eval(parse(text=))` ...

```
library(timeDate)
hdates <- list()
i <- 1
for (h in listHolidays('US')) {
    hdates[[i]] <- eval(parse(text=paste0(h, "(2018)")))
    i <- i + 1
}
```

Or a more concise method ...

```
lapply(listHolidays('US'), function(x) eval(parse(text=paste0(x, "(2018)"))))
```

Or if you want to get named list elements ...

```
sapply(listHolidays('US'), function(x) eval(parse(text=paste0(x, "(2018)"))))
```